# Convert JDBC con to C3P0

Tags: jdbc, c3p0

I've got a JDBC connection:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1/";
String dbName = "users";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "superadmin";
String password = "p@ssword";

try {
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
```

And i'm trying to convert it to c3p0

```
  ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
  cpds.setDriverClass( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" );
  cpds.setJdbcUrl( "jdbc:mysql://1.1.1.1/" );
  cpds.setUser("superadmin");
  cpds.setPassword("p@ssword");

  cpds.setMinPoolSize(5);
  cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
  cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
  cpds.setMaxStatements(180);

  Connection con = (Connection) cpds.getConnection();
```

But it won't convert over, i've tried to use some unwrap() method but still can't get it working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unwrap, and you don't need to cast what is already a Connection to a Connection.

You do need to use the correct jdbcUrl though. Compare your jdbcUrl argument to DriverManager.getConnection() with the jdbcUrl you've set on the ComboPooledDataSource. The latter is missing the last part of the jdbcUrl, the database name.